# How to include headers and footers for pages between chapters?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, templates, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{mwrep}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{opening}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{closing}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{c1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{c2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

How can I include page numbers on empty pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openright` causes a `\cleardoublepage` to be issued before the start of a new chapter. And, `\cleardoublepage` is defined as

```
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page\else
      \hbox{}\thispagestyle{blank}\newpage
      \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
  \fi}
```

Note the `\thispagestyle{blank}` which clears any page headers/footers on the page. Removing that via a redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` will help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{mwrep}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{opening}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{closing}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page\else
      \hbox{}\newpage% previously included \thispagestyle{blank}
      \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{c1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{c2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

This is similar to Gonzalo's answer, but allows you to modify the actual page style used for these blank pages, if needed.​

Answer (score 5):

You can define a new page style adding the page number in the desired position and then `\let` the `blank` page style (internally used by mwrep for the empty pages) to be this newly defined one; a simple example adding page numbers centered in the footer (of course, you can use one of your already existing styles):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{mwrep}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{opening}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{closing}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}

\fancypagestyle{myempty}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@blank\ps@myempty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{c1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{c2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```